# Remove some particular keywords in a column from a dataframe and save it to json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

have a dataframe with two columns  a and b , have to remove leading 141 from the dataframe in b columns

```
a         b

mark     14150

john     14160

jack     14130

harry     14180

jacob     14110
```

How to remove leading 141 from dataframe and then save the dataframe   to json like this

```
[{
        "a": "mark",
        "b": "50"
    },
    {
        "a": "john",
        "b": "60"

    }, {
        "a": "jack",
        "b": "30"

    }, {
        "a": "harry",
        "b": "80"
    },
    {
        "a": "jacob",
        "b": "10"

    }
]
```

Comment: have you tried `pandas apply` function and `to_json` ?

Comment: or maybe use the replace on pandas series `df['b'] = df['b'].replace({'141':''})`

Comment: Generating a json ?

Comment: `df.to_json('data.json', orient='records', lines=True)` try this

Comment: it is not in  array and separated by ,

Comment: Your json that you have put as an example isn't a valid json, Make it a valid JSON.

Comment: `df.to_json(orient='records')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove starting 141 only, you need to use `regex`
sample code is as follows

```
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(str)
df.replace(to_replace={'b' : r'^141'}, value='', regex=True).to_json(orient='records')
```

which will give you the following output

```
[{"a":"mark","b":"50"},{"a":"john","b":"60"},{"a":"jack","b":"30"},{"a":"harry","b":"80"},{"a":"jacob","b":"10"},{"a":"test","b":"241410"}]
```